# Can I make a Loki 32-bit version?

Tags: release-loki, cpu, sources

What would it take to create an unofficial 32-bit version of Loki?
What would be the steps required to build it from the source?
What would be missing or non-functional?
If someone provided an ISO, would it be made available on the website?

Comment: What's with the downvoting? Isn't there lots of users still using non 64-bit processors? Wouldn't they also want an UX-oriented distro?

Comment: I agree that this question should not be down-voted. @Knu is only asking if there is a 32-bit version present or is it possible to build one via existing scripts

Comment: @atur also **how**; detailed instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: With Arch Linux dropping 32-bit, general support for 32-bit will be on the way out everywhere on Linux, unless you want to use loads of outdated packages! http://www.pcworld.com/article/3164876/linux/arch-linux-pulls-the-plug-on-32-bit.html

Answer (score 9):

## What would it take to create an unofficial 32-bit version of Loki?

A lot of work without using our existing build infrastructure.

## What would be the steps required to build it from the source?

Again, a lot of work and fiddling. I don't believe there are succinct instructions anywhere.

## What would be missing or non-functional?

Nothing, so long as everything is built correctly, all 64-bit things should be portable to 32-bit.

## If someone provided an ISO, would it be made available on the website?

No. elementary are perfectly capable of making a 32-bit build, but any 32-bit only computer is not going to run the system very well. This is a council decision and will not sway because a community member has built one. It would remain an unofficial build, and directly calling it elementary OS would likely infringe on trademarks.

Comment: Are you sure nothing was stripped? Wouldn't it require to re-add stuff that were necessary for 32-bit processors? If so, was there a commit which covered that process? Was the choice of dropping 32-bit processors supported by hard evidences? I think *most* "32-bit only computer" currently running on freya would handle loki just fine.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. There shouldn't be anything that requires anything other than changing the packages out. I'm not sure we ever had to take a commit action, just never ran a build for 32-bit ISO.

The hard evidence was that 32-bit was nowhere near as popular a choice, and most of those machines can run 64-bit.

I don't think there have been and 32-bit only processors from Intel since around 2003. elementary has recommended a dual-core 64-bit processor for a while now.

Comment: "just never ran a build for 32-bit ISO" > Lots of users wish you would do one and put it somewhere.

Comment: Intel Atom netbooks from around 2010 are 32bit only. On the other hand even Freya didn't work properly on those.

Answer (score 2):

> What would it take to create an unofficial 32-bit version of Loki?
>
> What would be the steps required to build it from the source?

elementary OS has substantial information on getting started on their official website. Try working around with the information given at [Desktop Development](https://elementary.io/get-involved#desktop-development).

> What would be missing or non-functional?

If you are talking about the difference in 32-bit and 64-bit, then (apart from the obvious one's) that's for you, the developer, to decide!

> If someone provided an ISO, would it be made available on the website?

The guys at elementary are in a better position to answer! Get in touch with them via Twitter, etc. If having a 32-bit version does fall into their plan (and they aren't working on it).

Comment: This is vague. The first 2 questions require detailed answers.

Comment: I have deliberately kept it vague, for you to spend time 'researching' into it. Indeed the first 2 answers require in-depth explanation but that's for you to dive into and look up. You've been given a certain direction by the answer from @lewis (and less from mine).

Comment: I guess you are completely missing the point of the Q&A system. The bounty will be awarded to the one who will make that effort, *obviously*.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to downvote. This shows no effort whatsoever. This is generic and devoid of any substance: I don't understand the upvotes.

Comment: `elementary OS has substantial information on getting started on their official website. Try working around with the information given at Desktop Development.`  -   @knu is asking to built the 32-bit system,  not the apps...